# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct in c#

Tags: c#, partial-classes

this is my code

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 public partial class Class1 
  {

     public void method2() 
      {

          }

   }
```

I saw the solution for brackets problem but its in proper manner as you can see . whats the cause of this error can any one help me? i am using asp.net 1.1.

Comment: The code above compiles perfectly well. But you usually put your class inside a namespace.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this block of code. The error must be coming from a different piece of code. could you post all of the code in the file?

Comment: What error are you getting. The code you have supplied will compile perfectly.

Comment: Please don't vote to close just because it works on your machine. That is selfish.

Comment: pls uplift your vote to this question thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `partial` keyword is not supported in C# 1.x. You need to update your framework to v2.0 at least.

Comment: Hi Danny pls uplift my vote because currently my account is banned to ask question.

Answer (score 1):

`Partial` classes are not supported in C# 1.x.

Comment: hi abdul please uplift my vote for question so that I can ask questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial classes are not supported in C# 1.x. This will fix it.